# undefined offset 151?

Tags: php, arrays

i have no idea what the undefined offset 151 means, but i do know it's having a tizzy fit with the process i'm using to flip the ascii values around. Here's the code it doesn't like:

```
$secondb = $array1[$i2] / 10;
$firstb = $array1[$i2] % 10;
```

it's having that error out of this "for" loop:

```
    for($i2 = 0; $i2 < $amt1; $i2++);
    {
        $secondb = $array1[$i2] / 10;
        $firstb = $array1[$i2] % 10;
        $firstb = $firstb * 10;
        $array1[$i2] = $firstb + $secondb;
    }
```

more code:

```
function decoding($inputs)
{
    $inputs = base64_decode($inputs);
    $amt1 = strlen($inputs);
    $array1 = str_split($inputs);
    for($i2 = 0; $i2 < $amt1; $i2++);
        {
            $secondb = $array1[$i2] / 10;
            $firstb = $array1[$i2] % 10;
            $firstb = $firstb * 10;
            $array1[$i2] = $firstb + $secondb;
        }
        $inputs = implode($array1);
}
```

Comment: means that $array1[151] is not set therefore its undefined.

Comment: Always go with `isset()` before doing anything. Or try `foreach(`

Answer (score 1):

Undefined offset 151 means that you're checking if the array contains an 151th element.

Mind posting more code, that relates to your for loop? We can't do anything without knowing the value of `$amt1`.

Comment: Once more code is posted, I'll be editing this post so it'll be an answer, plus it answered the topic's title(undefined offset 151?), in my eyes it's an answer, so that's why I posted it as one.

Comment: well $amt1 is the length of the text to have their ascii flipped around, i did strlen() to the input of a lot of textareas, that's what $amt1 stands for

Comment: what does strlen return? Note that an array is index based and starts at 0, strlen counts from 1 to infinity. Therefor you should extract one from the check in your forloop.

Comment: strlen is returning the length of the string to be either coded/decoded, then I turn it into an array so I can work with it, then implode it back to string

Comment: What is the number that strlen returns?

Comment: for some reason it's echoing 2 less than what it should. i.e. "jacob"= 3 and cannon = 4 0.o

Comment: Looks like your error is somewhere else, try to debug your code by echoing values, and see if you're getting what you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

When you divide `$array1[$i2]/10` and `$array1[$i2]%10` first value of `$i2` is `0` and is not allowed to execute division by 0. To skip division by 0 I suggest you to make inside the for loop an if condition and skip division by 0, or to set the start value of `$i2` to `1`.

`for($i2 = 1, $i2< $amt1+1 ; i++){//your code}`

Comment: but he is not dividing $i2 to 0

Comment: $i2 is the place holder in the array count